# trying to access a ManyToManyField from db query but returning None

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

Im tring to access a ManyToManyFireld property after model query but get back `None`.

This is what the model looks like.

```
class Role(models.Model):
    ROLES = Choices('user', 'staff', 'admin')
    user = AutoOneToOneField(
        'account.User',
        related_name='_role',
        primary_key=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    role = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ROLES, default=ROLES.user)
    locations = models.ManyToManyField('location.Location', related_name='_role', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '<Role: user={0} ({1})>'.format(self.user_id, self.role)
```

When i call locations on the Role lookup i get back `location.Location.None` and this is what the query lookup looks like.

```
user_role = Role.objects.get(pk='123249882323')
role_locations = user_role.locations
print(role_locations) => location.Location.None
```

I want `role_locations` to return all the locations associated with the `Role`

Comment: `user_role.locations.all()`

Comment: Thank you it worked. @DanielRoseman